# Transcluding in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to understand this idea of creating directives in angularjs.
The reason is obvious angular 1.? Is finishing an angular 2.? Is it completely different? So I am trying to find a way to easy cross this gap. And I found this:
[link](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/creating-container-components-part-2-angular-1-directives).
I am java and c++ programmer starting his frontend journey, and maybe not everything is clear for me, but I can't figure out what transclude-to or transclude-id is?
Where is it come from? In all of documentation I have been searched I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the front-end world!
Transclude is a bit difficult to understand, maybe it will be a better choice to leave for now... I Deeply recommand you to start with this [intro course](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/) of angular 1.x.

Moreover, you should learn HTML, CSS and Javascript basics for building a strong base for the next steps. You can start [here](https://github.com/tojibon/awesome-web-developer).